# How can I detect if YouTube videos have been removed using their iFrame API

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to detect if a video has been removed or is no longer available on Youtube using the iFrame API?

The following code will detect changes to the youtube iframe but the only data point I can find thats remotely close is `-3` which means unstarted but this could be applicable to any working video as well.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eezdLm)

```
<iframe id="yt-iframe" width="630" height="354" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Rlm8YH2i9gY?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.id = 'yt-script';
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    console.log('yt scripts loaded');
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('yt-iframe', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log('video player ready');
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log(event.data);

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can detect before playing the video by checking the duration of the video, if duration of the video is `0` seconds then it is highly likely to be deleted/can't be played

```
<iframe id="yt-iframe" width="630" height="354" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tPEE9ZwTmy0?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.id = 'yt-script';
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    console.log('YT scripts loaded');
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('yt-iframe', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log('Video player ready');
        if (event.target.getDuration() <= 0) {
            console.log('Video likely to be removed');
        }
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setup an `onError` event handler and check for `event.data === 100`. The [YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onError) describes all of the player error events.

Comment: I could add an event listener on `onError` but this will only trigger when a user has pressed Play on the video... is there a way you can detect this just on player load?

Comment: I don't think so, no. When you click on the player, it sends a request to YouTube itself to grab the video info. Only then does the player know that the video has been removed and then lets your application know. The only way to know this before displaying the iframe would be to use the official YouTube API directly.

Answer (score 0):

No, atleast not straightforward.